# If a left ideal of R is a direct summand of R, is I an injective R-module?

Tags: homological-algebra, projective-module, injective-module

This was an exercise question I encountered in the book on Homological algebra by Vermani. I am unable to prove it or find a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is **No**:
(I'll only consider commutative rings, henceforth called just *rings*.)

a) A ring is called *self-injective* if it is injective as a module over itself.
 For example $\mathbb Z$ is not self-injective and neither is $R=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ because a product of rings is self-injective iff each factor is ([Lam](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Lectures_on_Modules_and_Rings.html?id=r9VoYbk-8c4C&redir_esc=y) page 65).

b) Now   I claim that $I=0\times \mathbb Z\subset R$ is a supplemented ideal which is not injective.
Indeed if $I$ were injective, so would be its twin $J= \mathbb Z\times 0$ and so would be their direct sum $R=I\oplus J$ (a finite direct sum of injectives is injective) .
Hence  $R$ would be (self-) injective, which ( as noticed above) is not true.
This contradiction shows that  actually $I$ is *not* injective, even though it is supplemented.